# how to parse a nested json array

Tags: php, json

I have a json as below,

```
{
   "responseHeader":{
      "status":0,
      "QTime":1
   },
   "spellcheck":{
      "suggestions":[
         "goo",
         {
            "numFound":5,
            "startOffset":0,
            "endOffset":3,
            "suggestion":[
               "good",
               "googl",
               "goodby",
               "goos",
               "goodwil"
            ]
         },
         "collation",
         "good"
      ]
   }
}
```

I tried the below php code to get the list of elements in the suggestion, i.e, good,google,goodby,goos,goodwill

```
$myArray = json_decode($response, true);
foreach ($myArray['spellcheck']['suggestion'] as $doc) {
   echo $doc;
}
```

But get this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: suggestion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ir/suggestions.php on line 9
```

How to get the individual elements of suggestion?

Comment: Missing `s` in the key.

Comment: This question is just based on a small typo / (formerly: "too localized").

Comment: Per what @mario was saying, you're using $myArray['spellcheck']['suggestion'] instead of $myArray['spellcheck']['suggestions'].

Comment: I get 
Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ir/suggestions.php on line 12
Arraycollationeither .. line 12 is echo $doc;

Answer (score 1):

It's just a spelling mistake with "suggestions" your array index missing "s" (it was suggestion)

```
$myArray = json_decode($response, true);
foreach ($myArray['spellcheck']['suggestions'] as $doc) {
   echo $doc;
}
```